# Latexmk: too many tabulars

Tags: tables

I have a `tabular` that contains multiple `tabular`s. I'm doing this to generate a math worksheet. Here is an example:

```
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccccccccc}
\begin{tabular}{rr}&\phantom{00}3\\\times&\phantom{00}4\\\hline&12\end{tabular}&
\begin{tabular}{rr}&\phantom{00}1\\\times&\phantom{00}7\\\hline&7\end{tabular}&
\begin{tabular}{rr}&\phantom{00}6\\\times&\phantom{00}1\\\hline&6\end{tabular}&
.
.
.
\begin{tabular}{rr}&\phantom{0}11\\\times&\phantom{00}1\\\hline&11\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
```

I'm using LatexMK to render, but it doesn't want to do its job when the number of `tabular`s reaches around 50. How do I make it work?
As far as I can tell, it doesn't throw any errors. That might be because of my fiddling with the files, though.
Overleaf seems to handle it just fine.

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Are you sure that Overleaf doesn't actually give you an error but you just don't notice because it gave you a PDF? We see that **a lot** sadly. You cannot have more cols in the outer tabular than you specified in `\begin{tabular}{cccccccccccccccc}`.

Comment: What exactly are you doing that needs such a large nested table?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! As far as can be concluded from code fragment, you not need nested `tabular`s at all. Please provide an sketch, that you like to achieve. One way is that instead of nested `tabulars` you use `\makwcell{....}`.

Comment: If you want columns with a given width, you can use `\makebox[width]{...}` or `\parbox{width}{...}` instead.  That is what I do.  (http://www.elfsoft2000.com/worksheets/index.htm)

Comment: daleif - That's right, it inserts a minor error and then wraps around. I found this out in Overleaf. I need this to make a multiplication sheet for a 3rd grader.
Zarko - see above.
John - I don't need a given width, I just need it to render when the number of `tabular`s get up to 100 or so.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you need to do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newdimen\mulw  \mulw=3em
\def\mul #1x#2=#3#4 {\vbox{\hbox to\mulw{\hfil$#1$ }\hbox to\mulw{$\times\hfil#2$ }%
   \smallskip\hrule\smallskip \hbox to\mulw{\hfil$#3#4$ }}\hskip1em plus.3em\relax}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\mul 3 x 4 = 12
\mul 1 x 7 = 7
\mul 1 x 6 = 6
\mul 5 x 5 = 25
\mul 1 x 1 = 1

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly as is in @wipet's answer (+1) but more elementary with use of the `\makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{12pt}
    \begin{array}{*{10}{c}}
\makecell[tr]{ 3 \\ \times 4 \\ \hline = 12 }&
\makecell[tr]{ 1 \\ \times 7 \\ \hline = 7  }&
\makecell[tr]{ 1 \\ \times 6 \\ \hline = 6  }&
\makecell[tr]{ 5 \\ \times 5 \\ \hline = 25 }&
\makecell[tr]{ 1 \\ \times 1 \\ \hline = 1  }&
%
\makecell[tr]{ 3 \\ \times 4 \\ \hline = 12 }&
\makecell[tr]{ 1 \\ \times 7 \\ \hline = 7  }&
\makecell[tr]{ 1 \\ \times 6 \\ \hline = 6  }&
\makecell[tr]{ 5 \\ \times 5 \\ \hline = 25 }&
\makecell[tr]{ 1 \\ \times 1 \\ \hline = 1  }
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]